# Deleting Items from a Listview through the Use of checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My program takes a checkboxed item and depending on the serial number that is present on the item on the invoice, subtracts one from the amount list
I have the following in a listview on a details page which I added with the following code:

Item - Low Socks(pink)
Serial # - 34-75-860
Price - 5.89
Amount - 12

Except they are in columns instead of rows like above

```
Dim items As New ListViewItem
    items = ListView1.Items.Add("Low Socks(Pink)")
    items.SubItems.Add("34-75-860")
    items.SubItems.Add("$5.89")
    items.SubItems.Add("12")

    items = ListView1.Items.Add("Low Socks(Black)")
    items.SubItems.Add("34-75-900")
    items.SubItems.Add("$5.89")
    items.SubItems.Add("25")

    items = ListView1.Items.Add("Low Socks(Red)")
    items.SubItems.Add("34-75-756")
    items.SubItems.Add("$5.89")
    items.SubItems.Add("10")

    items = ListView1.Items.Add("Low Socks(Orange)")
    items.SubItems.Add("34-75-234")
    items.SubItems.Add("$5.89")
    items.SubItems.Add("34")

    items = ListView1.Items.Add("Low Socks(Blue)")
    items.SubItems.Add("34-75-598")
    items.SubItems.Add("$5.89")
    items.SubItems.Add("23")
End Sub
```

Under my invoice page I have checkboxes next to the items on the invoice. When the checkbox is clicked I want the amount to decrease by one. I will go in later and change it to the actual amount it needs to be depending on how many of that item they ordered... my coding for my checkbox is this:

```
Dim item As ListViewItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    'count the number of items in itemdetails2 listview
    count = ItemDetails2.ListView1.Items.Count - 1

    'loop to read each item in the list
    For i = 1 To count

        If i > count Then Exit For

        item = ItemDetails2.ListView1.Items(i)

        'compare the item to the serial number
        If item.Checked = True Then

            If (item.SubItems(0).Text = "34-75-860") Then
                item.SubItems(2).Text -= 1
            End If

            i = i + 1
            count = count - 1
        End If

    Next

    ItemDetails2.Show()
End Sub
```

Right now it doesn't look like it does anything. I have tried changing my index's on my subitems to 1 and 3 instead of 0 and 2 but i figured because they are subitems that they need to be subitem index 0 and subitem index 2 since there is one item and three subitems to that one item. if that makes sense....
please help.

Answer (score 2):

Without digging into your indexing stuff i can notice that your are treating **strings as like as numeric**

```
item.SubItems(2).Text -= 1
```

When you should try :

```
item.SubItems(2).Text -= CStr(CDec(item.SubItems(2).Text) - 1D)
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: definitely makes sense that that would be necessary and I change that in my coding but it still isn't working. I also tried using the other index amount but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Amen, I think you meant to use = instead of -= in your suggestion.